# HTML5 img size attributes

Tags: html

If I have an image that is 600x600 and I want to display it in 100x100 on a mobile device.
Should I resize the image 1st in Photoshop or should I just use width/height attributes (will this method force users to download a large image 1st and then resize it ?).

I know it is possible to resize using JS

Comment: With the width and height set to a smaller (or greater) width/height, it's still the same image, thus the same size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The browser can resize images dynamically using CSS, but they doesn't always look as good as doing it in Photoshop. You should resize it for mobile to reduce the file size and bandwidth required.